# Flask python loop.index modulo

Tags: python, flask, modulo, werkzeug

Hi i'm trying to list some elements which divided by a clearfix div after every 3rd element. This is what I tried that doesn't work. How can I do modulo in flask?

```
{% for i in props %}
<li class="col-xs-4">
    <label class="basic-medium-black">
         <span class="icon-check {% if i in user.props %}active{% endif %}"></span>
         {% filter upper %}{{ i.prop_name }} {% endfilter %}
    </label>
</li>

****************This Part:******
{% if loop.index % 3 == 0 %}
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
{% endif %}
********************************

{% endfor %}
```

What should I put for modulo insted of "%" ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: are you looking for a different answer than that below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a modulo, you can also use the the [`batch()` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#batch) to group your items, allowing you to put a clear fix after every group:

```
{% for row in props|batch(3) %}
    {% for i in row %}
    <li class="col-xs-4">
        <label class="basic-medium-black">
             <span class="icon-check {% if i in user.props %}active{% endif %}"></span>
             {% filter upper %}{{ i.prop_name }} {% endfilter %}
        </label>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}

    <div class="clearfix"></div>        
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the built in variable test [divisibleby](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#divisibleby) like below.

```
{% if loop.index is divisibleby 3 %}
```

or

```
{% if loop.index is divisibleby(3) %}
```